# Hyper Linking to inline Form Label

Tags: flask-sqlalchemy, flask-admin

I am working with several levels of nested models.

For example, I have Test -> section -> question -> choice

where -> represents a 1 to many relationship.

I want to be able to go to the edit page of the inline model's using some kind of hyperlink.

This is an example image of where the link should be (ideally):

[image]

The highlighted area is where I want the hyperlink to be.

Currently there are two issues:

1. I want the inline form to show Section #id and not Section #1 , #2 etc.
2. I want the highlighted section to take me to the edit page of the Section, where I will be able to inline edit Questions and so on.

How can I do it in flask admin ?

Answer (score 0):

You can add `hybrid_property` to **model** like this:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.hybrid import hybrid_property

class Section(db.Model):
    @hybrid_property
    def link(self):
        # check id for new model (not show link)
        if self.id:
            return '/section/edit/?id={0}'.format(self.id)

    @link.setter
    def link(self, value):
        pass
```

and **inline_models** looks so:

```
inline_models = (
    (Section, {
        'form_extra_fields': {
            'link': LinkField(label=''),
        },
        'form_rules': ('link',)
    }),
)
```

where `LinkField` is a custom wtf field, eg:

```
from wtforms import TextField
from wtforms.widgets import HTMLString

class LinkWidget(object):

    def __call__(self, field, **kwargs):
        html = ''
        if field.object_data:
            html = '<a href="{0}" class="alert-link">Go to record</a>'.format(field.object_data)

        return HTMLString(html)

class LinkField(TextField):
    widget = LinkWidget()
```

Screen:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8n1Og.png)

Also you can override **inline_list_base.html** but it's not recommended.